# The connection point "filter parameter" on does not allow multiple connections

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a custom web part which does not allow multiple connection.
Scenario : I've added the custom web part on the page, added 2 lists on the same page.

Step 1 : I connect List 1 to web part and implement my functionality

Step 2 : I delete List 1

Step 3 : I get my custom error message that list name is invalid.[As required for the functionality]

Step 4 : I edit web part , and try to connect it to List 2

Step 5 : Error message received

> "The connection point "filter parameter" on
>   "g_789a749a_836c_45c4_b247_f4bfa28b94a3" does not allow multiple
>   connections.

Stack Trace

> WebPartPageUserException: The connection point "filter parameter" on
>   "g_789a749a_836c_45c4_b247_f4bfa28b94a3" does not allow multiple
>   connections.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CanSPConnectWebPartsCore(WebPart
>   provider, ProviderConnectionPoint providerConnectionPoint, WebPart
>   consumer, ConsumerConnectionPoint consumerConnectionPoint,
>   WebPartTransformer transformer, Boolean throwOnError) +2369
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.SPConnectWebParts(WebPart
>   provider, ProviderConnectionPoint providerConnectionPoint, WebPart
>   consumer, ConsumerConnectionPoint consumerConnectionPoint,
>   WebPartTransformer transformer, Boolean bCheck) +96
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Communication.PersistConnection.CreateConnection(String
>   xFormTypeName, String xFormInfo) +630
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Communication.PersistConnection..ctor(ConnectionDesigner
>   designer, SPWebPartManager manager) +1517
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Communication.ConnectionDesigner.PersistChangedConnections()
>   +63  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateConnectionDesigner()
>   +437 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ActivateConnections()
>   +361 System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.OnPageLoadComplete(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +70 System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +0  System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
>   +11046222  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3160

I am think of checking weather the web part has any connection or could be connected to the list.

Comment: Could you provide code from your webpart, concerned with connections? Which interface do you implement?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding AllowsMultipleConnections:

```
[ConnectionConsumer("Filter", "UniqueFilterName", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
public void GetConnectionInterface(IWebPartParameters pProvider)
{
}
```